# SINGLE PRODUCT AT A TIME

Tags: graph, sequence, multiplication, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have sequences like :

1:1,2,3,4,...10

2:1,2,3,4,...10

Similarly ,a3,a4,a5,..a

I have (≤15) queries , and in each query :

two numbers  and  are given , for eg if =1 and =2, have to calculate  such that :

=1∗1+2∗2+3∗3+....+10∗10

as p is large we need to take modulus by 2^32

Is there any way to answer each query in (1) time?

Comment: Do you have any constraint regarding the time/space complexity of the preprocessing? For example, if you would pre-compute a nxn matrix holding the results for all possible pairs of  i and j, you could answer each query in O(1). Does that count?

Comment: Yes we need to precompute only in O(n) time

Comment: Mh ok right. On a second look, it is not clear to me what the problem is. Since 10 is constant and all arithmetic is performed modulo 2^32, meaning it can be performed in constant time, for any given i and j we can easily compute p in constant time, using (a+b) mod m = (a mod m) + (b mod m) and (a*b) mod m = (a mod m) * (b mod m). Am I missing anything?

Comment: I just used n = 10 here but n can go up to 1e5

Comment: But that's still a constant, right?